# HTML Range element value not updating with Angular6 function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, slider

I am trying to get access to the changing values of a series of HTML range sliders.

Here is how they're instantiated:

```
<li *ngFor="let rgbVal of rgbVals; let i=index">
            {{i}}: {{rgbVal}} <br>
            <div class="color-box" [style.backgroundColor]="rgbVal"></div>
            <div class="slideContainer" >
                <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="30"  class="slider" id="shade{{i}}" step="1" (change) = "update(i)"  >

            </div>


        </li>
```

This is the Typescript function I have in my .ts function that should be able to access the value of the sliders:

```
update(i){
var id = "shade"+i;
var slider = document.getElementById(id);
console.log(slider.getAttribute("value"));}
```

The value once I move the slider stays constant & unchanged, no matter which slider I move or how much I move it.

Interestingly enough, if I run this code:

```
 update(i){
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
console.log(sliders);}
```

And then in the console open up the HTML container and look at the value field of each slider, it is updated as I move it.

I also tried

```
slider = sliders[i];
console.log(slider.getAttribute("value");
```

And that stayed constant regardless of change, even though that slider when viewed as a part of the sliders object allowed the value to be updated.

I am baffled by this one and can't find any similar errors online, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that `slider.getAttribute("value")` reads the value of the attribute, not the value of the input, so it will always say `30`.

What you need is:

```
update(i: number) {
    const id = `shade${i}`;
    const slider = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLInputElement;
    console.log(slider.value);
}
```